# EJB annotation not working

Tags: hibernate, cassandra, ejb, wildfly

I have a problem with my EJB annotations:

I have a DAO:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class CassandraDAO<T extends Serializable> extends AbstractDAO {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "JPAService", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
  private EntityManager em;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    System.out.println("***************** init CassandraDAO ***************************");
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void destroy() {
    System.out.println("***************** destroying CassandraDAO *************************");
    if (em.isOpen()) {
      em.close();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public EntityManager getManager() {
    return em;
  }

  @Override
  public void setManager(EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
  }
}
```

And there are several DAOs that extends this DAO:

```
@Stateless
public class IOConfigurationDAO extends CassandraDAO<IOConfiguration> {
...
}
```

And here is how I use the DAO:

```
public class AddAlertTest extends TestCase {
  @EJB
  private IOConfigurationDAO ioConfigurationDAO;
  public void test() {
      ioConfigurationDAO.getManager().getTransaction().begin();
      IOConfiguration ioConfig = new IOConfiguration("CH1");
      ioConfigurationDAO.getManager().persist(ioConfig);
      ioConfigurationDAO.getManager().getTransaction().commit();
      int oldSize = ioConfig.getAlerts() == null ? 0 : ioConfig.getAlerts().size();
      System.out.println("Created IO configuration with id " + ioConfig.getIoConfigurationId());

      ioConfigurationDAO.getManager().getTransaction().begin();
      Alert alert = ioConfigurationDAO.addAlert(ioConfig,
          Operators[(int) (Math.random() * Operators.length)], new Double(Math.random() * 100));
      ioConfigurationDAO.getManager().getTransaction().commit();
      int newSize = ioConfig.getAlerts().size();
      System.out.println("Created new Alert with id " + alert.getAlertId());
      System.out.println("Alert list: " + ioConfig.getAlerts());
      System.out.println("Alert is connected to " + alert.getIoConfiguration());

      assertEquals(oldSize + 1, newSize);
      assertNotNull(ioConfigurationDAO.getManager().find(Alert.class, alert.getAlertId()));

      ioConfigurationDAO.getManager().getTransaction().begin();
      ioConfigurationDAO.getManager().remove(ioConfig);
      ioConfigurationDAO.getManager().getTransaction().commit();
      System.out.println("Deleted IO configuration with id " + ioConfig.getIoConfigurationId());
  }
```

But my IOConfigurationDAO is always null, so my persistenceContext annotation doesn't work at all. And there is nothing printed out in my console, so my postConstruct annotations doesn't work as well.

Here is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">        
    <persistence-unit name="JPAService">            
        <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>    
        <class>com.sensorhound.aigateway.domain.Alert</class>
        <class>com.sensorhound.aigateway.domain.DataSeriesMeta</class>
        <class>com.sensorhound.aigateway.domain.IOConfiguration</class>
        <class>com.sensorhound.aigateway.domain.NodeData</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="JBossAS" />
            <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:5.0" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="cassandra_experimental"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host" value="127.0.0.1:9042"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="dev"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none"></property>
            <property name = "hibernate.show_sql" value = "true" />
            <property name = "hibernate.format_sql" value = "true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I don't know what is wrong in my configuration. Someone please help me. If you need more information, I am willing to share.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to run this as a unit test? You will never get injection unless you're using something like Arquillian or some other standalone EJB container to support it.

Comment: I gave you the answer to reason of the uninjected beans. please accept it if it was useful for you. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work of the DI annotations (@Inject, @EJB, @PersistenceContext,...) made by the container. When you run a unit test, the test run out of the container. So the injectable attributes stay null. For unit tests always mock this kind of dependencies. Learn a little bit about managed beans (CDI,JSF), unit testing and Mocking.

Answer (score 0):

When an EJB A extends another EJB B, the client which is using B by injection, is not automatically inheriting all the methods of the upper class A. Access to EJB is infact by means of a proxy created ad hoc.

In other words, if you inject `IOConfigurationDAO` you are using the proxy for that class, all the other business methods of the extended class are not visible by the client. The lifecycle ones `@PostConstruct` etc.. are not invoked.

Also, the design looks quite strange to me, a @Stateless that inherit from @Singleton.

Comment: Hi, Leonardo, thanks for your comment. I have copied code the after PostConstruct and PreDestroy annotations to my IOConfigurationDAO and replaced the Stateless annotation before my IOConfigurationDAO with Singleton annotation. Now I have a new error: Error injecting resource into CDI managed bean. Can't find a resource named java:comp/env/com.sensorhound.aigateway.ws.endpoints.IOConfigurationEndPoint/ioConfigurationDAO. I googled this error and someone recommend to use CDI instead of EJB, I tried but it didn't work. Is there something wrong with my database connection configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to get EJB in my unit test to work. But I got my EJB working in the project. I just switch to stateful EJB since my DAO is making some modification in the database and copy the method I had in the DAO's parent class to the DAO. Thanks!